# ESQL convert to binary

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

just wondering how to convert integers from XML to Binary PIC 9(4) BINARY

Currently I have

```
SET OutputRoot.DFDL.ORDERS.NUMBER_OF_ITEMS = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.XMLNSC.p:Order.p:Order_Items.p:Item[]);
```

Cobol CopyBook

```
NUMBER-OF-ITEMS PIC 9(4) BINARY
```

is there any way I can do to convert to Binary in that line. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved. No esql does the convertion, the dfdl parse does it. all good